# WCF works locally but returns 404 on remote server

Tags: asp.net, wcf

When i host my service and client on same  server  and in client config works fine on local server.

//Code

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/RequestService/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="RequestService.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
  </client>
```

Not working on local server but working on other server.

//Code

```
<client> 
  <endpoint address="http://www.xxxxx.com/RequestService/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="RequestService.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
  </client>
```

Why I'm getting  that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just setting `useDefaultWebProxy="false"` in binding in web.config of client.